# Surface SDK Generating Touch Events in code

Tags: touch, pixelsense

Im just wanting to know how about generating touch events in code (if it is possible) in the surface sdk on a MS surface. i.e. Using x and y points i want to simulate a touch down at that location. How would I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to simulate touch points check out [MultiTouchVista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) depending on your scenario you might need to create your own InputProvider.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804820(v=surface.10).aspx ) showing how to create an application that uses the simulation API.

Comment: This is mutually exclusive to receiving real touch input

Comment: We are using the Surface 2.0 Sdk. The simulation API was only available in 1.0 SDK.